# qemu-system-x64_86 high CPU comsumption, much higher than the processes inside the guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, ubuntu-18.04

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 with several virtual machines running in it using kvm. Using top inside the VM it never goes CPU consumption over 30%, however, if I check the qemu-system-x86_64 processes in the host I usually have over 100%. Why is this happening? Can I improve this? and the last one, is there a known relationship between CPU consumption inside the guest and the host?

Comment: Can you add the output of "virsh dumpxml <vmname>" (without quotes and replace <vmname> with your vm name or uuid)

Comment: Yes, sure... It happens with several VMs, this is one example of xml file: https://pastebin.com/G83VFZmt